# I am using bootstrap to create a slide, but the second div which contains is longer then the slide div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[image]

In order to make second div appear above the slide div, I make the second div `position:absolute`. Because the first div is slide..so I cannot put second div inside the first div. How to solve it?

```
<div class="carousel slide">
  <div class="carousel-inner" style="height:1000px">
    <div class="item active">
      <div class="fill" style="background-image:url(picture.jpg);"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div>some form.....</div>
```

css

```
.fill {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-position: center;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
}
```

here are samples of how the images look
Desktop
[image: Desktop]
Mobile
[image: Mobile]

solved!!....

Comment: When you say above do you mean overlaid or on top of? Can you provide an image of what you are hoping to accomplish, the question at this point is unclear to me.

Comment: do you want the header and form to be persistent (always visible) or only show on one of the slides? currently your markup is showing the form outside of the slide markup?

Comment: @MrGood, I actually mean overlaid.....Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not completely clear on your question but here is a solution using standard bootstrap markup.

your issue was that you are trying to put the form markup after the carousel if you do indeed need it to overlap this is not the answer please clarify your question and i will revise the answer

If this is not what you are looking for let me know

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //console.log('Ready!')

})
```

```css
.carousel-inner .item {
  min-height: 80px;
 
}
#form_2 {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1000;
  display: none;
}
.form-cont {
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.5);
  border:1px solid #ccc;
  height: 300px;
  width: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 999;
  
  left: 25%;
  top:0;
  padding:10px;
}
.item img {
  min-height:300px;
}
.item.slide1 {
  background-color:red;
  }

.item.slide2 {
  background-color:lightblue;
  }
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="realtive">
  <div class="form-cont">



    <h4>Header</h4>
    <form class="form-inline">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputName2">Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputName2" placeholder="Jane Doe">
      </div>

      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Send invitation</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active slide1">
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/4hEOH.jpg" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        slide 1
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item slide2">
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/COO5g.jpg" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        slide 2
      </div>
    </div>
    ...
  </div>

  <!-- Controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I actually means that the whole screen is a slide, and the second div(div2) contains a form and a header is overlaying the slide....But div2 is longer than the slide..How to make the slide's height the same as the div2...see my picture provided above. Many Thanks.

Comment: add a min-height to it? I am still a little unclear your markup does not match your image

Comment: so the form is to always be overlaid above the slider?

Comment: - -The image provide is just created by power point....but just as an example. I think add a min-height may still not work on a mobile device?

Comment: =.=....Thanks anyway...I just solved it.... I spent nearly 6 hours......just add a height:1000px; in carousel-inner.....By the way, is there any other way that I don't need a fixed height, more flexible height when dealing with vary large screen and very small screen...

Comment: you may consider dropping the slider on the mobile the limited screen space does not make the slider very usable when a form has to cover it all

Comment: I have modified my answer, if this is this more what you are looking for consider accepting the answer. If not I recommend that you post your solution as an answer to make this post more useful for other users.

Comment: my form is transparent..so I have to have some images.. it seems just display a little part of a image. it is already responsive..just looks not clear. Is there a way can deal with it?...

Comment: what does not clear mean? Picture is worth a thousand words

Comment: =.=your code is correct....But I actually mean that I want the slider is larger than the form...Because initially i just set the height of slide is 100%......=.=I spent a stupid problem about 6 hours.....just did not realize it..